# Why are indexes not getting used

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table of the following form:

```
create table orpsnumericy2(o bigint, r bigint, p bigint, s bigint);
```

I have built 24 indexes over all the permutations of (o,r,p,s).

I have another table of the following form

```
create table dictionaryfull (id, stringvalue);
```

With 2 indexes: `(id, stringvalue)` and `(stringvalue, id)`

I created the indexes using create index command of postgres

Then I ran the following command:

```
explain select di1.stringvalue 
from orpsnumericy2 d1, orpsnumericy2 d2, dictionaryfull di1 
where d1.R=d2.S 
and d2.P=(select id from dictionaryFull where stringvalue='"hasSuccessor"') 
and d2.O=(select id from dictionaryFull where stringvalue='"William"') 
and d1.S=di1.id;
```

I obtained following plan from the command:

```
 Hash Join  (cost=8820530.24..35113870.90 rows=290 width=516)
   Hash Cond: (di1.id = d1.S)
   InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
     ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on dictionaryfull  (cost=71028.27..4406162.67 rows=1358357 width=8)
           Recheck Cond: ((stringvalue)::text = '"http://yago-knowledge.org/resource/hasSuccessor"'::text)
           ->  Bitmap Index Scan on dictionaryfull_stringvalue_id_idx  (cost=0.00..70688.68 rows=1358357 width=0)
                 Index Cond: ((stringvalue)::text = '"http://yago-knowledge.org/resource/hasSuccessor"'::text)
   InitPlan 2 (returns $1)
     ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on dictionaryfull  (cost=71028.27..4406162.67 rows=1358357 width=8)
           Recheck Cond: ((stringvalue)::text = '"http://yago-knowledge.org/resource/William_J._Murphy"'::text)
           ->  Bitmap Index Scan on dictionaryfull_stringvalue_id_idx  (cost=0.00..70688.68 rows=1358357 width=0)
                 Index Cond: ((stringvalue)::text = '"http://yago-knowledge.org/resource/William_J._Murphy"'::text)
   ->  Seq Scan on dictionaryfull di1  (cost=0.00..25274570.28 rows=271671328 width=524)
   ->  Hash  (cost=8203.39..8203.39 rows=122 width=8)
         ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..8203.39 rows=122 width=8)
               ->  Index Scan using opsr1 on orpsnumericy2 d2  (cost=0.00..279.67 rows=122 width=8)
                     Index Cond: ((O = $1) AND (P = $0))
               ->  Index Scan using rops1 on orpsnumericy2 d1  (cost=0.00..64.94 rows=1 width=16)
                     Index Cond: (R = d2.S)
```

Can someone please help me understand as to why the indexes of dictionary full are not getting used. And the reason as to why is the query so slow.

Also it will be great if someone could explain me the query plan in simple terms

EDIT: Can someone help me find an optimal query for:

```
  select di1.stringvalue, di2.stringvalue, di3.stringvalue   
  from orpsnumericy2 d1, orpsnumericy2 d2, dictionaryfull di1,
       dictionaryfull di2,dictionaryfull di3 
  where d1.reification=d2.S and d2.P=(select id
        from dictionaryFull where stringvalue='"hasSuccessor"')   
  and d2.O=(select id from dictionaryFull  
      where  stringvalue='"William_J._Murphy"')  
 and d1.S=di1.id  
 and d1.P=di2.id  
 and d1.O=di3.id
```

Comment: wow, you have all the column permutations as the indices.  That is dreadful please don't do that.

Comment: Have you run ANALYZE? Have you tuned the database from the default settings? What version of Postgresql? You show an `EXPLAIN` plan, how about an `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` plan instead.

Comment: is it mysql or postgresql?

Comment: For docs on explain: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Using_EXPLAIN

Comment: in the future please utilize sqlfiddle.

Comment: "*I have built 24 indexes over all the permutations*" - that's absolute overkill and not needed with Postgres. It can use more than one index for one table in a single query. You probably only need one index on each column (if at all)

Comment: updated, but you need to provide us the schemas.

Comment: you should try using proper join syntax, look into the SQL-92 Standard (as in 1992)

Answer (score 2):

```
select di1.stringvalue 
from orpsnumericy2 d1, orpsnumericy2 d2, dictionaryfull di1 
where d1.R=d2.S 
and d2.P=(select id from dictionaryFull where stringvalue='"hasSuccessor"') 
and d2.O=(select id from dictionaryFull where stringvalue='"William"') 
and d1.S=di1.id;
```

You have three tables here:

```
orpsnumericy2 d1 , orpsnumericy2 d2,dictionaryfull di1
```

you are failing to join them together correctly.

You need a condition for `d2.??? = di1.???`  that is why the query is "slow" .  Basically what is happening is you have a missing `Join` therefore you are getting close to a `cartesian product` in your query.  You **probably** want this condition at the end:

```
and d2.S=di1.id;
```

Further you may want to consider rewriting the query similar to this **NOT TESTED IN THE LEAST**:

```
   select di1.stringvalue
   from dictionaryfull di1
   join orpsnumericy2 d1 on d1.S = di1.id  
   join orpsnumericy2 d2 on d2.id = d1.id
    and d2.P=(select id from dictionaryFull where stringvalue='"hasSuccessor"') 
    and d2.O=(select id from dictionaryFull where stringvalue='"William"')
```

The query you have now is very different:

```
select di1.stringvalue, di2.stringvalue, di3.stringvalue   
  from orpsnumericy2 d1, orpsnumericy2 d2, dictionaryfull di1,
       dictionaryfull di2,dictionaryfull di3 
  where d1.reification=d2.S and d2.P=(select id
        from dictionaryFull where stringvalue='"hasSuccessor"')   
  and d2.O=(select id from dictionaryFull  
      where  stringvalue='"William_J._Murphy"')  
 and d1.S=di1.id  
 and d1.P=di2.id  
 and d1.O=di3.id
```

you now have FIVE tables:

```
orpsnumericy2 d1.orpsnumericy2 d2, dictionaryfull di1,  
dictionaryfull di2,dictionaryfull di3
```

Again what you are doing is just adding more complexity and failing to do proper joins.  My original solution still holds that you are missing joins.  So adding more tables isn't helping solve the problem.  Further you have yet to provide a sqlfiddle for us to actually see your schema.  It is all wild speculation on our parts in this question.

you need the following joins:

```
d1.x = d2.x
d1.x = d3.x
d2.x = d3.x
d1.x = di1.x
d1.x = di2.x
d1.x = di3.x
d2.x = di1.x
d2.x = di2.x
d2.x = di3.x
d3.x = di1.x
d3.x = di2.x
d3.x = di3.x
di1.x = di2.x
di1.x = di3.x
di2.x = di3.x
```

Comment: How can i include a join here

Comment: @AliceEverett `d1` and `d2` are the same table.  So the RDBMS is not "smart" enough to join them all together the way you think.

Comment: if i want to run these queries fast how can I run them?

Comment: Shouldnt postgreSQL be smart enough to itself re-write this query

Comment: @AliceEverett it is currently more accepted to use explicit joins vice the implicit version (your original version was implicit).  It should produce the same plan, but it is the more accepted way to write queries.

Comment: Can you please suggest as to how can I rewrite this query??

Comment: @AliceEverett add this to your original question.  The comments are not the place for this.

Comment: Done...added in the original question